# Make JPanel to the size of the child JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, jtextarea

I'm stuck at this problem for a couple of hours now. I want a `JPanel` to be the size of the `JTextArea`, which is in it. So here is my idea at which I need help. I want to program a messenger and I want to display my messages in a panel. My messages are panels that have a text area inside where the content of the message is shown. Now I want the panel to be the same size as the text area where the content is shown. The panel must have a maximum width but need to be smaller than this. Here is my code:

```
public class Message extends JPanel{

private NetworkMessage data;

private JTextArea content = new JTextArea();

public Message(NetworkMessage pData) {
    
    data = pData;
    
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
    content.setText("Hallo");
    
    
    content.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    content.setLineWrap(true);
    content.getWrapStyleWord();
    content.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));

    
    this.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Main.messengerFrame.getChatPanel().getWidth()/2 , 500));
    
    this.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
}

public NetworkMessage getData() {
    
    return data;}}
```

And here is what my program looks like right now: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDN8k.png)

Here is a Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    jf.setVisible(true);

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setBackground(new Color(255, 0 , 0));
    jp.setOpaque(true);
    jp.setVisible(true);

    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    jp2.setBackground(new Color(0, 255 , 0));
    jp2.setOpaque(true);
    jp2.setVisible(true);
    
    jp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 800));
    jp2.setMinimumSize(jp.getPreferredSize());
    jp2.setMaximumSize(jp.getPreferredSize());

    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    jta.setLineWrap(true);
    jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    
    jta.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
    
    jp2.add(jta);
    jp.add(jp2);
    jf.add(jp);
    jf.validate();
}
}
```

And here is what the Minimal, Reproducible Example looks like: [screenshot form Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd5ec.png)

I want the green panel (`jp2`) to be the same size as the `JTextArea`. But the panel should have a maximum width and if the text area is wider than the maximum width, the text should have line breaks so that it gets longer but not wider.

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow, can u post a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Maybe try invoking `setPreferredSize(content.getPreferredSize());` and `validate();` afterwards.

Comment: no that doesn't make any differece

Comment: Do you have to set a preferredSize? If I remove the preferredSize and minimumSize it works fine for me.

Comment: But then die Textarea doesn’t resize. It should be wider and „infinite“ long. When I leave the maximum, than there’s a limit for the size of the textarea